# How to avoid PDOStatement::bindParam messing with the referenced value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phalcon

I'm facing the problem described by Steve M but on a "large scale", please see for details http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#94711

I'm using Phalcon, but it mostly acts as a wrapper, the question must not be limited by that. The detailed issue is here – https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2111

**TL;DR Int values in array are converted to strings, as such:**

```
var_dump($params); // array(2) { [0]=> int(6609) [1]=> int(6664) }
$adapter->fetchAll($sql, Db::FETCH_ASSOC, $params);
var_dump($params); // array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "6609" [1]=> string(4) "6664" }
```

I reuse that array later and heavily rely on the ints. When they turn into strings it spoils all the joy… No matter what I do with it (copies values with `foreach` , `array_merge` into new array, `ArrayObject::getArrayCopy` to get a copy) the original values keep changing (and values of other arrays they've been copied from). They only way with copying that works is:

```
$adapter->fetchAll($sql, Db::FETCH_ASSOC, unserialize(serialize(($params)));
```

That feels like an massive overkill. Another solution that seems to work is below, though `$paramTypes` is not documented ([Phalcon code that handles it](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/1.3.0/ext/db/adapter/pdo.c#L382) for those who're interested).

```
$paramTypes = [];                                                                                                                                               
foreach ($params as $param) {                                                   
    if (is_int($param)) {                                                       
        $paramTypes[] = \PDO::PARAM_INT;                                        
    } else {                                                                    
        $paramTypes[] = null;                                                   
    }                                                                           
}                                                                               
$rows = $this->adapter->fetchAll($sql, Db::FETCH_ASSOC, $params, $paramTypes);
```

To me it seems to be the best approach, BUT here is the same method described by Axeia that received negative feedback – http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#97130.

**My questions:**

1. Why it might be a bad idea doing it the way [Axeia](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#97130) suggests?
2. Can you suggest another alternative to this? Apart from converting the modified array back to integers.
3. WTF???!!! Why it need to take a reference and modify it? Should there be a bug report???

Many thanks ya all!

Comment: Use bindValue instead of bindParam and then the original variables won't be changed.

Comment: Use object oriented programming, for example data transfer objects, and it won't change anything...

Comment: O really. Object oriented programming? Sounds interesting, I might google that…

Comment: @Mike, that would be the best way out of this if it's changed in the framework, thanks.

Comment: @IanBytchek I didn't realize phalcon didn't have a way to do that and I don't see anything similar to Laravel's `DB::connection()->getPdo();` which would return the raw, underlying PDO instance. What about just setting a temporary variable every time and bind that instead of the "actual" one?

Comment: It has `$adapter->getInternalHandler()`, which is the least obvious of all. I'd rather stick with the framework and not reinvent the wheel, this theoretical question mostly. The solution I have works, but I feel it might be way better (without changing all the code that depends on it). I suggested what you said about bindValue and send a PR. Just compiled it and it works perfectly. This world doesn't need bindParam when it has bindValue :)

Comment: As you can see, SO is not suitable for such questions. Only ones that can get "use oop" answers are welcomed by the community. Someone should run another site where programming questions have to be asked.

Comment: it seems turning off emulation mode fixes the issue.

Comment: Haha, well you never know when that oop might help you. Tried that. Didn't for me. I'm actually going to check out php-mysqlnd. Apparently its from the future.

Comment: Not the oop, the emulation mode turning off :)

Comment: Why oh why do people not Read The Manual `Phalcon\Db::FETCH_NUM` Page 385

Comment: @davidstrachan Why oh why do people read the actual question. +5 for not doing it but staying positive.

Comment: So, mysqlnd did the trick?

Comment: Nope. It's there by default, someone just tried to be a smart ass about it. I suggested to the guys to change bindParam with bindValue (https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2111), thanks to your post on it. I compiled it locally and works perfectly. Do you know anything about what kowach says there? Is that for real? Sounds too good to be true with almost no performance implications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the fact that Phalcon inadequately did use `PDOStatement::bindParam` instead of `PDOStatement::bindValue`. The big [debate](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2111) is covered on the github and followed with a [pull request](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/pull/2249/commits), which eventually has been merged into version 1.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Your mysql database will keep data type as it is width php-mysqlnd driver and these two attributes set to false:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$parm1 = 2;
var_dump($parm1);
//  int(2)

$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT *  FROM test.table1  WHERE id = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $parm1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($parm1);
// int(2)

var_dump($data);

/* you get nice and clean result:
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["id"]=>  int(2)
    ["name"]=>  string(3) "XYZ"
    ["someint"]=>  int(543)
    ["somefloat"]=>   float(1000.0001220703)
  }
}

And table is:
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `someint` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `somefloat` float(10,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've replied to this at github https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/issues/2111#issuecomment-37133780. You are missing a few points. The attributes play no role I believe in keeping the params unmodified, explicitly setting the type int does `$sth->bindParam(1, $parm1, PDO::PARAM_INT);` – which is what I'm trying to avoid doing manually.